# 'Dotnet failed to pack' error when trying to publish a powershell module to local repository

Tags: .net, macos, powershell

I'm working on MacOS 10.15, and I have a clone of the [PSRabbitMq](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSRabbitMq) powershell module. I'm trying to publish it into a local repository I created:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name TestPSRepo -SourceLocation '/tmp/powershell_test_repository' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Publish-Module -Path '<path_to_module>/PSRabbitMq' -Repository TestPSRepo -NuGetApiKey 'test' -Verbose
```

Getting this error:

```
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : Failed to generate the compressed file for module '/usr/local/bin/dotnet failed to pack: error
'.
At /Users/my_user/.local/share/powershell/Modules/PowerShellGet/2.2.1/PSModule.psm1:10944 char:17
+ ...             Publish-PSArtifactUtility @PublishPSArtifactUtility_Param ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToCreateCompressedModule,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

(I have `dotnet-runtime-3.0.0-osx` installed)

Does anyone know what is this error all about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

I had `dotnet` installed and not `dotnet-sdk`.

```
brew cask uninstall dotnet
brew cask install dotnet-sdk
```

solved my issue.

I hope it will be useful for someone else sometime.

Comment: Useful for me : ) Same on Windows. I updated dotnet runtime and sdk and then publishing worked